# What exactly happens to a file when it is uploaded?

Tags: php, javascript, upload, metadata, dropbox

My question exactly wants to know whether it is possible to upload all files first and then extract their metadata later sometimes?
I am developing a web api which will allow me to upload files and extract their metadata. 
The way I have been using to extract metadata is to upload one file at a time and extract its metadata and print it out.
I wish to implement this on **client side** (javascript) and also be able to allow users to download the uploaded files from the server ( a dropbox like implementation which also allows metadata manipulation ).
Is it possible?

A very sincere thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned already, on the server the files are placed in a temporary folder from where you can do anything with them your heart desires.

If I understand multipart-HTTP requests correctly, they should be technically able to send multiple files, but for the bandwidth problems alone I'd not go this approach. Not even sure if the server side application, e.g. PHP, could deal with that.

I hope I understood your Use Case correctly. For your case I'd recommend sending the files via AJAX requests to a PHP script in the background, so for the user it appears like all files are uploaded first before anything else happens. In the background you loop over the selected files and send them to the server, one file at the time. The server can read the metadata and send it back to the browser, where you can further process it in JS.

I never did this myself, but this looks like a common problem to me, so there should be plenty of info in the web. This one looks nice: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ (first hit on Google for "jquery multi file upload")

Answer (score 0):

When uploading files, your webserver will be accepting the files and storing them in a temporary folder until the file uploads are complete.

After the file uploads have completed, THEN the PHP script is started.

So any PHP work (such as extracting metadata, if that is done in PHP) will thus happen AFTER the files complete uploading.

PS. I don't think you can access local files with javascript on client side.

Comment: Currently I am building this API on a local system.Then,javascript should do the job.I know that in php,it is way more easier to manipulate data,but architecturally,javascript suits my purpose better.

Comment: @ShubhamLalwani Before even starting, check if Javascript can even access local files. As I wrote in my PS, I think Javascript is sandboxed and cannot access local files.

Comment: Yeah,it is possible to access local file metadata using JS.
For example,I can get the name,size,last modified date and the type using JS.Here is a code which does that - 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: @ShubhamLalwani I doubt that is what nl-x was talking about.  Yes, you can access some information about files via javascript, less so in non file-api browsers.  You cannot, however, access any arbitrary file client-side.  More possibilities open up with browsers that support the filesystem API, but this still only gives you access to files within a sandbox.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is a quite common request. Usually, there is some HTML/JS client user interface which collects all the file names in appropriate fields, either a fixed list or some dynamically generated fields. I.e. the file upload fields in the browser may be "hidden" by display:none in order to have these necessary fields but show something more fancy to the user.

As the others stated: after the submit of the enclosing form, all is sent to the server and stored in a temp dir (php.ini setting). The php script, that will get the post action of the form then is kicked off and is able to fetch the files from the dir:

```
$inputName = $_GET['userfile'];
$fileName  = $_FILES[$inputName]['name'];
$tempLoc   = $_FILES[$inputName]['tmp_name'];
```